# Radeon Pitcairn drivers for iMac running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, mac, matlab

Recently wiped an iMac "Core i5" 3.3 27-Inch (5K, Late 2015), and installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as the only OS. All working fine except for the graphics; for example the following error message outputs when I start MATLAB:

```
com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: X11GLXDrawableFactory - Could not initialize shared resources for X11GraphicsDevice[type .x11, connection :0, unitID 0, handle 0x0, owner false, ResourceToolkitLock[obj 0x2e153efd, isOwner false, <56f605f5, 316e54b9>[count 0, qsz 0, owner <NULL>]]]
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:326)
    at jogamp.opengl.SharedResourceRunner.run(SharedResourceRunner.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:688)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:580)
    at jogamp.opengl.x11.glx.X11GLXDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(X11GLXDrawableFactory.java:297)
    ... 2 more
Exception in thread "Startup Class Loader" java.lang.InternalError: XXX0 profile[1]: GL3bc -> profileImpl GL4bc !!! not mapped 
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.computeProfileMap(GLProfile.java:2047)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDeviceCritical(GLProfile.java:1917)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDevice(GLProfile.java:1866)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices(GLProfile.java:1835)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.access$000(GLProfile.java:79)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile$1.run(GLProfile.java:229)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton(GLProfile.java:215)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.JavaSceneServerPeer.initializeJOGL(JavaSceneServerPeer.java:150)
    at com.mathworks.hg.peer.JavaSceneServerPeer.<clinit>(JavaSceneServerPeer.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.mathworks.mde.desk.StartupClassLoader.loadClass(StartupClassLoader.java:241)
    at com.mathworks.mde.desk.StartupClassLoader.access$800(StartupClassLoader.java:25)
    at com.mathworks.mde.desk.StartupClassLoader$2.run(StartupClassLoader.java:228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The graphics on the system is a Radeon HD 7850 Pitcairn. I'm using the open source radeon driver, default from the OS. I understand this is the only option for flavour 16.04?  Is there a better driver option or configuration or tweak on this one?  Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Were u able to fix this?

Comment: No, sadly, any suggestions?

Comment: Try the proprietary driver. I am not having much luck with its installation on Linux mint, but u might succeed on Mac. This is a graphics driver issue.